# Average over hard to define partition

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have this table:

```
create table t (value int, dt date);

 value |     dt     
-------+------------
    10 | 2012-10-30
    15 | 2012-10-29
  null | 2012-10-28
  null | 2012-10-27
     7 | 2012-10-26
```

And I want this output:

```
 value |     dt     
-------+------------
    10 | 2012-10-30
     5 | 2012-10-29
     5 | 2012-10-28
     5 | 2012-10-27
     7 | 2012-10-26
```

I want the null values, as well as the one previous non null value, to be replaced by the average of the previous not null value when the table is ordered by date descending. In this example the value 15 is the previous not null value of the next two nulls. So 15 / 3 = 5.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6a0c7/1)

Comment: +1 Very nice question. And it has everything it needs - well, I infer PostgreSQL 9.2 from the fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a surprisingly simple solution:

```
SELECT max(value) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)
      / count(*)  OVER (PARTITION BY grp) AS value
      ,dt
FROM   (
   SELECT *, count(value) OVER (ORDER BY dt DESC) AS grp
   FROM   t
   ) a;
```

[**-> sqlfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6a0c7/2)

Since `count()` ignores `NULL` values, you can use a running count (default in window function) to group values quickly (-> `grp`).

Every group has exactly *one* non-null value, so we can use min / max / sum to get to the same result in another window function on top of that. Divide by the number of members (`count(*)` this time, to count `NULL` values!) in the `grp` and we are done.

Comment: Nice, but seems PostgreSQL-specific.

Comment: @jsalvata: "But"? Did you notice the [PostgreSQL] tag? Also, this is standard SQL. [-> **sqlfiddle for SQL server** with identical query](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fb11e/1).

Comment: No, I didn't. Crappy mySQL doesn't support it. Yes, it is standard.

Answer (score 1):

As a puzzle, this is a solution... in practice it may perform horribly depending on the nature of your data. Watch your indexes, in any case:

```
create database tmp;
create table t (value float, dt date); -- if you use int, you need to care about rounding
insert into t values (10, '2012-10-30'), (15, '2012-10-29'), (null, '2012-10-28'), (null, '2012-10-27'), (7, '2012-10-26');

select t1.dt, t1.value, t2.dt, t2.value, count(*) cnt 
from t t1, t t2, t t3 
where 
    t2.dt >= t1.dt and t2.value is not null 
    and not exists (
        select * 
        from t 
        where t.dt < t2.dt and t.dt >= t1.dt and t.value is not null
    ) 
    and t3.dt <= t2.dt 
    and not exists (
        select * 
        from t where t.dt >= t3.dt and t.dt < t2.dt and t.value is not null
    ) 
group by t1.dt;

+------------+-------+------------+-------+-----+
| dt         | value | dt         | value | cnt |
+------------+-------+------------+-------+-----+
| 2012-10-26 |     7 | 2012-10-26 |     7 |   1 |
| 2012-10-27 |  NULL | 2012-10-29 |    15 |   3 |
| 2012-10-28 |  NULL | 2012-10-29 |    15 |   3 |
| 2012-10-29 |    15 | 2012-10-29 |    15 |   3 |
| 2012-10-30 |    10 | 2012-10-30 |    10 |   1 |
+------------+-------+------------+-------+-----+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select dt, value/cnt 
from (
    select t1.dt , t2.value, count(*) cnt 
    from t t1, t t2, t t3 
    where 
        t2.dt >= t1.dt and t2.value is not null 
        and not exists (
            select * 
            from t 
            where t.dt < t2.dt and t.dt >= t1.dt and t.value is not null
        ) 
    and t3.dt <= t2.dt 
    and not exists (
        select * 
        from t 
        where t.dt >= t3.dt and t.dt < t2.dt and t.value is not null
    ) 
    group by t1.dt
) x;

+------------+-----------+
| dt         | value/cnt |
+------------+-----------+
| 2012-10-26 |         7 |
| 2012-10-27 |         5 |
| 2012-10-28 |         5 |
| 2012-10-29 |         5 |
| 2012-10-30 |        10 |
+------------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Explanation:

- t1 is the original table
- t2 is the row in the table with the least greater date with a non-null value
- t3 are all rows in between, so we can group by the others and count

Sorry I can't be clearer. It is confusing for me too :-)

Comment: If it's too complicated to explain, chances are, it's just too complicated. :)